# Nash Equilibrium of 2-players game

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming, game-theory

I have a rather interesting exercise in Game Theory.

*Assume there is a 2-players game, and player $i$ has $n_i$ pure strategies. The game is given by listing the payoffs for each player for each $n_1 × n_2$ possible plays.*

*Give a polynomial time algorithm to check if there is a Nash equilibrium for the game in which each player mixes between at most two strategies.
Give a ﬁnite algorithm for finding a Nash equilibrium for general games with two players. Your algorithm may run in exponential time.*

The answer to the first question hopefully can be solved by convex optimization.

In the second case some kind of exhauivet search can be used.

Unfortunately I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did we get stuck?  We expect you to make a serious effort on your own first.  This is not the place to dump your homework exercise; we don't solve your exercise for you.  However, if you have made a serious effort and have gotten stuck on some specific point, asking a narrowly focused question about that might be more suitable for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Given a mixed strategy for both players, how can you verify that it's a Nash equilibrium? How many potential strategies do you need to consider in both cases?

Comment: For given strategy of the opponent I need to find the best mixed strategy response, with support of size two, so there are $n^2_i$  cases to check. Right?

Comment: The definition of Nash equilibrium doesn't restrict the best response; the strategies forming the Nash equilibrium should be at least as good as *any* response. However, one thing that could help is that there is always a best response which is a *pure* strategy.

Comment: answer to the hint: given the mixed strategies for both players, I will check that the payoff of pure strategies in the support of mixed strategy have a maximal payoff (and of course the same for all pure strategies in the support) given the mixed strategy of the opponent.

Comment: the goal is reduced to find that the "maximal payoff" can have at most two pure strategies, the problem is I don't get how to show this from side of each player.

Comment: You just need to check all possible strategies of the type being considered.